# (Re)Calibrating the touch screen on HP Laserjet Pro MFP

Tags: printer, touchscreen

I have a HP Laserjet Pro 400 color MFP m475dw.  I am running OSX Snow Leopard.

While I was cleaning dust from the control panel touch screen, it spontaneously decided to calibrate the touch screen (when swiping over the screen I probably got extremely (un)lucky).  Problem is that I can't find any way to start the touch screen calibration from outside the touch screen control panel and the only way I've found to do a factory reset on the damn thing is through the menus in the touch screen.

Is there a magic dance I can do when restarting the printer to get it back to factory defaults, or better, anyway to start the screen calibration?

Update:

The touchscreen is totally out of whack, meaning that the locations I press on the touch screen don't cause a response in the same location in the printer.  This means, for example, that to press "Settings" on the printer means pressing somewhere near the center of the touch screen.  This also means that some buttons are (or at least, seem) totally inaccessible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a newer firmware, the calibration is started from the integrated web configuration facility, which can be reached with the HP Utility on OS X, via the "Open embedded web server" button.

From there, navigating to System -> Service, there is a "Start calibration" button.  Pressing this gave me the touch screen calibration screen on the printer and it actually worked this time.

[image: HP web configuration]

Comment: I was going crazy trying to figure out why the screen stopped working. Calibrating the screen fixed the issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

[There should be "HP Solution Center" software](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c02463264&cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en) on your PC that you installed the print drivers on, it can do most everything the touchscreen can do. Use the "settings" button at the bottom of the main screen.

Not sure what you mean by re-calibrate.

[Here is the manuals page for that model printer](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/manualCategory?cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en&product=5043320&query=%20MFP%20m475dw&tool=&)

.
[image]

.
[image]

Comment: The touchscreen is totally out of whack, meaning that the locations I press on the touch screen don't cause a response in the same location in the printer.  This means, for example, that to press "Settings" on the printer means pressing somewhere near the center of the touch screen.  This also means that some buttons are (or at least, seem) totally inaccessible.

Comment: While I am able to configure almost everything via the network, the touchscreen is used to activate functionality, such as "copy" and "scan".  This is also a network printer and it should be usable even when my desktop is not powered on.

Comment: The "user guide" I linked to tells how to do a factory reset, but requires using the touchscreen. You might try disconnecting the poser cord, hold the power button down while you connect power back, keep holding it see if it does a factory reset.

Comment: The power button trick doesn't seem to work, just tried it, again.

Comment: If no one else answers, all I can suggest is to sign up and make a post over here...http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/Printers-LaserJet/bd-p/bsc-413

Answer (score 1):

I was hopeless and I just clicked both side of the touch screen several times (Middle of both right/left side of the touch screen) as it is shown in the figure until I get a calibrating Setup appeared in the touch screen!

Then I followed the steps (Press on the Dots ● shown on the touch screen) until getting the Home Window of the printer. Hope this will help you :)

[image]

Comment: THANKS! After a few printed configuration reports as a side effect, I got the calibration screen as well.  I had tried clicking both sides of the screen, but apparently with not enough perseverance :)  Now it worked, thank you so much!

Comment: My joy was premature.  I do get the calibration screen ok and I get to press the two dots, but the calibration is still out of whack after this step is completed.  I guess I have to return the device.

Answer (score 1):

You have to press simultanously on the left side in the lower corner of the black space and on the right side in the middle of the black space, that's the trick I've found out after about half an hour testing! Now it works again!

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem, I could even calibrate the screen using the method noted above with touching the specific areas simultaneously on the black sides and doing a factory reset. The screen would calibrate but not work afterward.

To confirm, I also updated my firmware then used the calibration feature on the printer's web page and it worked! Finally, I don't know if it worked because I updated the firmware or because I used the calibration feature afterward. I didn't check to see if it just needed a firmware update before calibrating it. Regardless, thanks to everyone for their posts and suggestions. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I too had the exact same problem, while senselessly cleaning dust off the touchscreen.  None of the buttons worked right, and I could not get it fixed.  Ended up downloading the updated firmware from the HP website (for my exact printer/operating system) and presto! the "Start Calibration" button appeared under the system tab of the "HP Device Toolbox" (similar to others' "HP Solution Center") and worked perfectly as stated by other posters.  Thanks so much to everyone for helping with posts and suggestions!!